# How can I look for *not* <something> in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

How can I do something like this:

```
db.my_collection.find('myObj.myField' : { $not : /abc/i });
```

Which means to retrieve all the objects in which `myField` value does *not* contain `abc` substring (case-insensitive).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> db.bar.insert({name : "joe", address : { street : "brodway", zip : 232 } })
> db.bar.insert({name : "alex", address : { street : "nelken", zip : 4 } })

> db.bar.find({ "address.street" : { $not : /Nelken/i }})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f1810e0ef7b8b0317a8ad1f"), "name" : "joe", "address" : { "street" : "brodway", "zip" : 232 } }
>
```

Comment: oh :) sometimes the truth is stranger then fiction :))) thanks!